# Constructor with list of objects and generics

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have a constructor like this:

```
public SomeObject(int len, float f, ArrayList<CustomObjectA> list) {  
  // code for constructor  
  this.list = list;
}
```

I want to add another constructor like this:

```
public SomeObject(int len, float f, ArrayList<CustomObjectB> listB) {  
  // code for constructor   
  this.listB = listB;  
}
```

I can't because I get the erasure error which I can understand.
What is the best way to approach this?
I wouldn't want to make it `ArrayList<Object>` the parameter and I would prefer to have 2 separate list objects as member variables instead of 1 (I am talking about `list` and `listB`)

Comment: If you want to use two list then put two variables (ArrayList) like class properties, and set each one by the setter metod, can you explain a little more? Maybe I can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Use static factory methods instead of a constructor, and give each factory method a different name.

Also, use List rather than ArrayList.

```
private List<CustomObjectA> listOfAs;
private List<CustomObjectB> listOfBs;

private SomeObject(int len, float f, List<CustomObjectA> listOfAs, List<CustomObjectA> listOfBs) {
    // ...
}

public static SomeObject createFromAs(int len, float f, List<CustomObjectA> list) {
    // construct the SomeObject; return it
}

public static SomeObject createFromBs(int len, float f, List<CustomObjectB> list) {
    // construct the SomeObject; return it
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the private constructor having 2 lists as arguments?

Comment: You can't have the different constructors like you did, but you can pass `null` for the list type you didn't get.

Comment: @LouisWasserman:Then why not make the constructor public in the first place and pass null?

Comment: Because that forces your users to deal with the messiness.  Hiding it behind factory methods lets you keep a clean API and lets you change it in the future.

Comment: This is the best answer.